Why is the `.getAnimations()` rejecting all promises when a HTML dialog element is closed?
I want to trigger a function after a dialog element is closed. I use transitions to fade out the dialog and it's backdrop, so I want to wait till all transitions are done.
I searched how to do this and implemented that feature (MDN Web Docs).
But sometimes the promises are rejected and sometimes the'll finish. I tried a lot of things with the transition-timing-functions and also without the new allow-discrete behavior, but it will still fail sometimes.
Anybody knows if this is correct behavior? Or can it be a bug in the browser?
I'm working on Chrome, because Safari and Firefox aren't supporting the overlay transition.


const $button = document.querySelector('button');
const $dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');

$dialog.addEventListener('close', async function() {
  const animations = $dialog.getAnimations();

  if (animations.length) {
    await Promise.any(animations.map(animation => animation.finished));
    console.log('After close');
  }
});

$button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if ($dialog.open) {
    $dialog.close();
  } else {
    $dialog.showModal();
  }
});
.dialog {
  --_transition-duration: 200ms;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.0625rem .5rem 0 rgb(0, 0, 0, .1);
  opacity: 0;
  overscroll-behavior: contain;
  padding: 0;
  transition-behavior: allow-discrete;
  transition-duration: var(--_transition-duration);
  transition-property: display, opacity, overlay, scale;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  width: min(calc(100% - 2rem), 30rem);

  &[open] {
    opacity: 1;
    scale: 1;

    &::backdrop {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }

  &::backdrop {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, .375);
    opacity: 0;
    transition-behavior: allow-discrete;
    transition-duration: var(--_transition-duration);
    transition-property: display, opacity, overlay;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
  }

  @starting-style {
    &[open] {
      opacity: 0;
      scale: .9;
    }

    &[open]::backdrop {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
}
<button>Open Modal</button>
<dialog class="dialog">
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam ipsum aut animi exercitationem, obcaecati recusandae rem mollitia qui voluptatum. Aliquid amet rerum magni, enim perferendis dignissimos officiis maxime unde tempore!</p>
  </div>
</dialog>




The finished promise of an animation is rejected if the animated element is removed before the animation finishes, as illustrated by the following snippet:


setTimeout(function() {
  b.style.opacity = 1;
  b.getAnimations()[0].finished.then(
    function() {
      console.log("Resolved");
    },
    function() {
      console.log("Rejected");
    });
}, 1);
button {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 5s;
}
<button id="b" onclick="this.remove()">Remove me</button>



Wait 5 seconds for the animation to finish and "Resolved" will be logged. Or press the button during these 5 seconds to remove it and "Rejected" will be logged.
I can imagine that the backdrop of your <dialog> element is likewise removed (or styled as display: none) when the dialog is closed.
Addendum: I observed (without being able to explain it) that the finished promise in your example is rejected with an error "The user aborted a request" when I close the dialog after having selected some of the text in it. You can observe that by replacing animation.finished with animation.finished.catch(console.error) in your code.

It's the display style that's set to none in this case.

@Kaiido but how come sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. It looks like it should work. Do you think it's normal behavior? Or can it be a bug?

It depends on whether the animation is still running when the dialog is closed.

But I am getting the current animations / transitions with the getAnimations function and wait till they are finished. Theoretically it shouldn't be possible then that it is finished before it is finished right?

Just removed the display property from the transition-property list and it seems te work. Also this functionality is in 'experimental phase', so yes, It could be that it isn't working properly. I'll try another way to know when the transitions on closing are done to do the callback at the correct moment.
